# PDO error "maximum of 2100 parameters" on update

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to build a dynamic update, but I get this error when I try to update

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 65536. SQL Server
>   supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.

Required data

```
$array = [
    'message' => 'test',
    'message_status' => false

];
$database->update('sms',$array,3);
```

function

```
 public function update($table,$data,$id)
    {
        try{
            $sql = sprintf("update %s set %s Where id = %b", $table,implode(' = ?,',
                    array_keys($data)).' = ?',$id);
            $statment = $this->Conn()->prepare($sql);
            $statment->execute($data);

        }catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many items are you passing in to be updated? The number 65536 is a full 16 bits so it looked like you hit some other limit too. (Hex 0xFFFF).

Comment: the array above only, just 2 columns!. is there problem with the query building code?

Comment: PDO execute with unnamed placeholders doesn't expect an array with keys>values. Try with `->execute(array_values($data))`

Comment: ohh  it works. Thank you JimL.  so I can't add associative array,  I didn't know what  because  I saw many people doing that!

Comment: You probably saw people using named placeholders `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id` which you pass like this to execute `->execute([':id' => 1])`, note the colon for the named parameters